# How to clear just the last drawn path not the whole view

Tags: android

I have a view on which I am drawing some text using Path on canvas. Now I need to clear only the last drawn path i.e. drawn without clearing the whole view because I want to further redraw and re-clear path.

I have already used `draw.Color(Color.BLACK)` but this turns my whole screen into black, but I need to clear only the last drawn path not the whole view.

Comment: I find out other way of solving this issue, Now i am just recreating my view instead of clearing canvas, and its working fine...

Comment: How you are recreating your view any code please ?